# jQuery interference in Magento Lightbox, Menu & Tabs

Tags: jquery, magento, lightbox, colorbox, magento-1.7

I am working on editing a template where I need to add a Lightbox that shows up some HTML content on product pages. Precisely, instead of "Add to Cart" button there will be a Button that pops over some inline lightbox content.

All the lightbox alternatives I've looked at, require me to inherit jQuery using CDN. Like this:
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

And the template I am using is using a bunch of custom scripts in head.phtml & other pages.
Like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/ver_menu.js');?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/custommenu.js');?>"></script>
```

So, when I add this line in head.phtml or even the product page, My Top Menu stops dropping down & The product information tabs stop working and all the information is displayed right on my product page (instead of appearing under their respective tabs).

Is there a way I can avoid this interference between the jQuery scripts to make the lightbox (on product page - view.phtml) work and not have my menu & information tabs affected.

Been struggling with this for a while and the theme authors aren't willing to help either.

I have already tried to play around with the placement of the jQuery Line I posted above, but no luck. Any way I can use the magento's core jQuery script to make my lightbox work...

Also, I am using colorbox for the lightbox effect. (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)

I can't do much but I can offer a dinner & a beer on me to whoever can help me get this resolved. Really counting on you guys...

Comment: go to this url https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js which you have provided and download the file include that in your js folder and use it like you are using other one

Comment: Did that Rahul but No Solution... '<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js');?>"></script>'

Comment: Make sure to use jQuery in noConlict() mode.

Comment: I looked into it @pspahn but I just wouldn't know where to start, there are so many jQuery scripts running in the template then Magento uses its own. Plus, its not the lightbox script thats causing this issue, its inheriting the javascript from the CDN (the first script line I posted in my question) that makes everything go coocoo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do this on this way i added this code in /templatefiolder/page/html/head.phtml:

```
 <!-- adding jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://linktoJquery/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
     var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
//]]>
</script>
```

I added this $j because of conflicts with prototype. In this case you always have to do jQuerythings like this:

```
<script>
// execute your scripts when DOM is ready. this is a good habit
$j(function() {     

    $j(".scrollable").scrollable();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery via CDN on a Magento site. It's going to cause problems. Instead, host it on your server. Open up the script, and add:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

at the end of the file. Rename it to something along the lines of jquery.min.no-conflict.js so that it's obvious to anyone in the future that it's running in noConflict() mode, and make sure it is loaded before any of your other jQuery based scripts.

Since you're in noConflict() mode, you should build any jQuery scripts using "jQuery" as the instantiator, not $ (which is used by Prototype, the javascript framework used in Magento 1.x).

Comment: Thank you...I realized where I was going wrong in implementing your first solution...Thanks for making it more clear

Answer (score 0):

The lightboxes you've tried are jQuery plugins, which require the jQuery library.  It doesn't matter if you host the library or let someone else host it (like a CDN).  If your page is already running a version of jQuery, you likely don't need to add anything at all.

If your page is using some other script that is making use of the $ alias, then you'll need to use noConflict as pspahn said.  After that, you'll no longer be able to use '$' as an alias for jQuery without creating a local scope and assigning it there.  Example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();</script>
<script src='jquery.colorbox-min.js'></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $ = jQuery; // create an alias for typing convenience
    $('a.example').colorbox();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for making it so easy and obvious for me to fix the issue.